# Join multiple fields from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I wanted to know if it was possible to make a select on a table that contains multiple field and join them in 1 result :

Example :

Table :

```
id
dayOne_City
dayTwo_City
dayThree_City
```

Result : one column that contains the rows of all the cities (Distinct).

2) Am i better to do a view if i have a lot of query to that specific list ?

3) should i do 3 select with union ?

Thank you

Comment: What you should do is refactor your database to have a related table.

Comment: you are right we made an error when we designed the tables ... paying the price now :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be fine with:

```
select dayOne_City from YourTable
UNION
select dayTwo_City from YourTable
UNION
select dayThree_City from YourTable
```

However, you should review your design to allow multiple cities per whatever-is-that-your-table stores. That is, create an actual many-to-many relationship by creating an intermediate table between `YourTable` and `Cities`.

Comment: Should i create a view from that or use it as is ? what if the city is associated to a region is there a way to generate 2 columns results ? (region - city)

Comment: About view creation: if you are viewing this information in multiple places then, yes, you should probably create a view. And Yes, you can have it associated with region: `inner join` each select with `Cities` (and maybe `Regions`) and get the desired region column.

Comment: The region is in the same table , same row as the city

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat_ws(',', id, dayOne_city, dayTwo_city, dayThree_city, etc...) as allInOne
```

Details on the function used [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws). However, I should ask why you're doing this. By joining the fields together, you're destroy any chance of reliably extracting/separating the data again later. Only do this kind of "bulking" if you never plan on using separate portions of the data elsewhere based on the results of this query.

Comment: sorry i think i dident explain correctly , i dont need to do a concat i want to extract all cities from all the fields